# How to stop array.some() from another function using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In my scenario, I have a some() or foreach loop. Once, my condition satisfied, I am calling another function. Once I have called this other function, current function some() or foreach needs to break. How to achieve this?

After satisfying my condition `if(value == 1){}` I am calling a function but same time need to stop this current loop.

```js
function one() {
  array.some {

    if (value == 1) {
      two(); // function call 
      return true; // It will execute next loop, but need to exit immediately calling two
    }
  }
}

function two() {
  // From here to stop the function one some() by passing return true.
}
```

Comment: `some()` should stop as soon as the callback function returns `true`.

Comment: `some` stops as soon as it finds one item in the array that matches the given condition.

Comment: `two()` should return a value. The `some()` callback function can `return true` whenever `two()` returns `true`.

Comment: Hi! *"`return true; // It will execute next loop, but need to exit immediately calling two`"* No, it won't. :-)  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Separately: Using `some` when you're not using its return value isn't really ideal. If you just need a loop that you stop, use `for-of` rather than `some`.

Comment: `Array.prototype.some` is used for its return value in that "some" elements meet some criteria. You seem to be using it in a very non-standard manner.

Comment: On top of that, `array.some { ... }` would be a syntax error at the very least.